# How to insert new element using content from sibling elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have some existing XML output in which I need to insert a new element that will contain both some hardcoded data and some dynamic data, which is derived from the values of two sibling elements.

I have tried several iterations of this but am unable to get any meaningful output

**XML Input:**

```
<ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <record>
                <field name="Client">Company X</field>
                <field name="TItle">Program Manager</field>
                <field name="ReqNumber">106839</field>
                <field name="JobBoardID">JB-10000</field>
                <field name="PostedDate">2019-04-03</field>
                <field name="City"></field>
                <field name="StateProvince"></field>
                <field name="Country">United States</field>
                <field name="Category">Professionals</field>
                <field name="JobText">Blah, blah, blah</field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Client">Company X</field>
                <field name="TItle">Director, Sales--Army</field>
                <field name="ReqNumber">106051</field>
                <field name="JobBoardID">JB-13262</field>
                <field name="PostedDate">2019-03-04</field>
                <field name="City"></field>
                <field name="StateProvince"></field>
                <field name="Country">United States</field>
                <field name="Category">Sales Workers</field>
                <field name="JobText">Blah, blah, blah</field>
            </record>
</ExportXML>
```

**Desired XML Output:**

```
<ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <record>
                <field name="Client">Company X</field>
                <field name="TItle">Program Manager</field>
                <field name="ReqNumber">106839</field>
                <field name="JobBoardID">JB-10000</field>
                <field name="PostedDate">2019-04-03</field>
                <field name="City"></field>
                <field name="StateProvince"></field>
                <field name="Country">United States</field>
                <field name="Category">Professionals</field>
                <field name="JobText">Blah, blah, blah</field>
                <field name="ApplyURL">https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/JB-10000/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job=106839</field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Client">Company X</field>
                <field name="TItle">Director, Sales--Army</field>
                <field name="ReqNumber">106051</field>
                <field name="JobBoardID">JB-13262</field>
                <field name="PostedDate">2019-03-04</field>
                <field name="City"></field>
                <field name="StateProvince"></field>
                <field name="Country">United States</field>
                <field name="Category">Sales Workers</field>
                <field name="JobText">Blah, blah, blah</field>
                <field name="ApplyURL">https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/JB-13262/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job=106051</field>
            </record>
</ExportXML>
```

As you can see in the code example above, I'd like to add a new "field" element with an attribute of "ApplyURL" that takes a hardcoded string (https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/) concatenates that with the value of the sibling field element with attribute "JobBoardID", concatenates that with the hardcoded string of "/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&job=" and concatenates that with the value of the sibling field element with attribute "ReqNumber".

I need this template rule to apply to all "record" nodes found in the XML document.

I've tried various approaches for this, but thus far have not had any success.  I'm new to XSLT, so not surprising.  I'm hoping someone who is more experienced with this can help me out.

Comment: Please post your latest or best trial, so we can show how to amend XSLT for desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building URL with [`concat`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_concat.html) for hard-coded and dynamic data. Be sure to assign a namespace prefix to XSLT such as below which uses *doc* since original input XML maintains a default namespace:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:doc="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" > 
   <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- Identity Transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 

   <!-- rewrite record node -->
   <xsl:template match="doc:record">
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:field"/>
        <xsl:variable name="url" select="concat('https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/',
                                                doc:field[@name='JobBoardID'], '/',
                                                '/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job=',
                                                doc:field[@name='ReqNumber'])" />
        <xsl:element name="field" namespace="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">ApplyURL</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$url"/>
        </xsl:element> 
      </xsl:copy>

   </xsl:template> 

</xsl:transform>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpy)

Comment: Parfait - you are a lifesaver!  It works like a charm!  Thanks so much for the quick help on this.  I'm learning a great deal about XSLT and your example really moves my understanding forward.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` instructions are useful when their QName are going to be dynamically defined. Otherwise, just use [literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#literal-result-element).

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:doc="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
               xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
               exclude-result-prefixes="doc"> 
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 

   <xsl:template match="doc:record">
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <field name="ApplyURL">
            <xsl:value-of 
            select="concat(
                'https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/',
                doc:field[@name='JobBoardID'],
                '/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job=',
                doc:field[@name='ReqNumber'])" />
        </field>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ExportXML  xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <record>
                <field name="Client">Company X</field>
                <field name="TItle">Program Manager</field>
                <field name="ReqNumber">106839</field>
                <field name="JobBoardID">JB-10000</field>
                <field name="PostedDate">2019-04-03</field>
                <field name="City"/>
                <field name="StateProvince"/>
                <field name="Country">United States</field>
                <field name="Category">Professionals</field>
                <field name="JobText">Blah, blah, blah</field>
                <field name="ApplyURL">https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/JB-10000/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job=106839</field>
            </record>
            <record>
                <field name="Client">Company X</field>
                <field name="TItle">Director, Sales--Army</field>
                <field name="ReqNumber">106051</field>
                <field name="JobBoardID">JB-13262</field>
                <field name="PostedDate">2019-03-04</field>
                <field name="City"/>
                <field name="StateProvince"/>
                <field name="Country">United States</field>
                <field name="Category">Sales Workers</field>
                <field name="JobText">Blah, blah, blah</field>
                <field name="ApplyURL">https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/JB-13262/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job=106051</field>
            </record>
</ExportXML>
```

That this is the best approach is confirmed by updating the transformation to XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
               xmlns:doc="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
               xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07"
               exclude-result-prefixes="doc"
               expand-text="yes">
   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>     

   <xsl:template match="doc:record">
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <field name="ApplyURL">https://www.fakedomain.org/careersection/{
                doc:field[@name='JobBoardID']}/jobapply.ftl?lang=en&amp;job={
                doc:field[@name='ReqNumber']}</field>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro.  Another great solution.  I was wondering the XSLT 3.0 version might look like.  Gotta love the simplicity that "mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"" provides...